# Magento 1 admin order column check if item got catalog price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, adminhtml

I want to edit the following file, that I copied to a local folder, and show a line if the product got a catalog price rule applied.

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
```

I already tried this, but that does not show any message, when it is applied. Because this gets the shopping cart price rule, instead of the catalog price rule. How can I get the catalog price rule id?

```
<?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()): ?>
    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
    <?php if($_item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '63'):?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('CUSTOM MESSAGE') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How did you override the template? Do you see your changes if you "hack" in the original template? With other words is the template overriding the problem or getting the applied price rule?

Comment: @HelgeB Already tried to add it into the original template, but it still does not show the message. For some reason it does not check if the SKU got a catalog price rule with id 63 applied.

Comment: There might be an issue if you would have more than one price rule applied. In that case you have a comma separated list returning. To be safe for that case you can try to check `if (in_array('63',explode(',',$_item->getAppliedRuleIds())))`. But I guess you have a logical issue here: the order items store only the cart rules not the catalog rules

Comment: @HelgeB Thanks! What I found is that `$_item->getAppliedRuleIds` shows the shopping cart price rule, instead of the catalog price rule. Is there a way to get the applied catalog price rule?

Comment: No, the catalog price rules are applied to products in a precalculation process, but as always there are workarounds :-) I post an answer with that approach but that will only work if you don't change applied rules. Otherwise you can get the catalog rules before an order will be saved and store them with the order.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment the catalog rules are not stored with an order or order item therefore you don't have a consisten history of the rules. However it is possible to get all the catalog rules matching for a product with the following code. The code is only for give an example, in order to get the applied rules the `sort_order` of the rules needs to be considered in the foreach loop as well as the `action_stop` parameter.

Since catalog rules may change over time it would be better to get this information on order creation time and store it somewhere with the order item.

I hope the example demonstrates the possibility to get the catalog rules matching for a specific product.

```
//the example should be usable in that way in your phtml file with the given $_item
//however I don't recommend to use it that way but to move the functionality in an appropriate Block or Helper
//and last I would recommend to store that information during the order creation process 
//(for example in a plugin after order place)


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$rule = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\RuleFactory')->create();

$order = $_item->getOrder();
$store = $order->getStore();
$date = $order->getCreatedAt();
$websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId();
$customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
$productId = $_item->getProductId();

//get the matching collection of catalog rules for the given order item
$ruleCollection = $rule->getRulesFromProduct($date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);

$customRuleApplied = false;

foreach ($ruleCollection as $rule){
    if ($rule['rule_id'] == '63'){
        $customRuleApplied = true;
        break;
    }
}
```